# Помогите переписать код для работы с файлами под работу с string

Tags: c#

```
public static void cryptFile(string key, string load, string save)
    {
        using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(load))
        {
            using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(save))
            {
                DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
                DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
                ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
                using (CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    inputStream.CopyTo(cryptostream);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void decryptFile(string key, string load, string save)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        DES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(load))
        {
            ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
            CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(inputStream,
               desdecrypt,
               CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(save))
            {
                cryptostreamDecr.CopyTo(outputStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Есть два метода, которые шифруют и дешифруют текстовые файлы(результат записывая в отдельный файл). Я затрудняюсь переписать эти два метода под работу с переменными, то есть:
1) Считываю текст файла в переменную string
2) Шифрую записанный в string текст
3) Дешифрую с string-а текст

Я пробовал через добавление StreamReader, но при записи в переменную содержание шифрованного контента портилось и выдавала исключение при попытке дешифровки.

Comment: Это неправильный подход. Строка — штука, зависящая от кодировки. Вы должны шифровать не строку, а _набор байт_ (например, массив, список или другую упорядоченную коллекцию).

Comment: Да я вот тоже заметил, что при шифровке в стринге иногда не та кодировка. Честно говоря, чет уже парюсь второй день, не могу переписать код, что под строку, что под масив байтов

Comment: Я бы предложил перевести весь ваш внутренний API на массивы байтов. То есть у вас будет `public static void cryptFile(byte[] key, string load, string save)` и `public static void decryptFile(string key, string load, string save)`. Читать файл в `string` не надо ни в коем случае, вы теряете его байты при этом.